# jupyterlab_code_formatter: multi-line list in code, specify items/characters per line?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, code-formatting, autopep8, black-code-formatter

jupyterlab_code_formatter installed for Jupyter lab
Black, isort, YAPF, Autopep8 added for  jupyterlab_code_formatter

Question: which config should I twist if I want the auto-formatted list to not be one item per line.

```
# what it is doing now (default setting, tried different config but no luck):
day_words = [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third",
    "fourth",
    "fifth",
    "sixth",
    "seventh",
    "eighth",
    "ninth",
    "tenth",
    "eleventh",
    "twelfth",
    "thirteenth",
    "fourteenth",
    "fifteenth",
    "sixteenth",
    "seventeenth",
    "eighteenth",
    "nineteenth",
    "twentieth",
    "twenty-first",
    "twenty-second",
    "twenty-third",
    "twenty-fourth",
    "twenty-fifth",
    "twenty-sixth",
    "twenty-seventh",
    "twenty-eighth",
    "twenty-ninth",
    "thirtieth",
    "thirty-first",
]
```

```
# what I want after hitting auto-format:

day_words = [
    "first", "second", "third",
    "fourth", "fifth", "sixth",
    "seventh", "eighth", "ninth",
    "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth",
    "thirteenth", "fourteenth", "fifteenth",
    "sixteenth", "seventeenth", "eighteenth",
    "nineteenth", "twentieth", "twenty-first",
    "twenty-second", "twenty-third", "twenty-fourth",
    "twenty-fifth", "twenty-sixth", "twenty-seventh",
    "twenty-eighth", "twenty-ninth", "thirtieth",
    "thirty-first",
]
```

tried twist isort multi_line_output to 0,1,2,3
tried twist autopep8 max_line_length to 120

it still auto-format my list to now item per line, which I know is not a big deal. But it is kinda too long when I have a long list